# Angular-UI Typeahead. How to disable few rows and not allow selection for those fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

In a normal Typeahead built by Angular UI

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" placeholder="Locations loaded via $http" typeahead="address for address in getLocation($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" class="form-control">
```

How do I disable some rows and not allow selection for those fields.

For example. Just like Select2 Disabled Options.

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an old question, but it seems still not answered.
What I did is create a custom PopupTemplate, even for different reasons before.
In this PopupTemplate you can use ng-class on the li-Element:
For the custom Template:

```
typeahead-popup-template-url="templates/typeaheadPopupTemplate.html"
```

In the template-file(you have to search for the right scope, though):

```
<li class="uib-typeahead-match" ng-repeat="match in matches" ng-class="{active: $parent.$parent.$parent.funcItmIsActive($index, $parent), disabled: $parent.$parent.$parent.funcItmDisabled(match) }" >
<div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
</li>
```

And then in the Controller:

```
$scope.funcItmDisabled = function (itm) {
                    let result = false;
//loading is to check, if the Control is loading atm. because the list is sometimes loaded from Service.
                    if (!$scope.loading && itm && itm.model && itm.model.itm) {
                        if ($scope.SelectionDisabledIf) {
                            result = itm.model.itm.DisabledFlag === true;
                        }

                    }
                    return result;
                };
```